# How long would it take for a sun-sized meatloaf as hot as the sun to cooldown?

Tags: thermodynamics

A thin steak cools off on my counter in a minute, but a very large roast will stay hot in the middle for an hour or more. Thermal mass seems to play a role here and presumably also the size of the actual object.

I'm trying to think of these principles in an extreme scenario. If I had a beef roast the size of the sun and as hot as the sun, how long would it take to cool down? We can assume that the roast is sitting in a room at 20c and that "cooling down" means reaching 100c or less perhaps at the center. It doesn't have to be beef, it could be steel or even the sun itself.

This really is not a question about fusion, fuel, gravity, collapsing stars, etc. I'm hoping we can ignore all of this and focus purely on the heat of things, even if the object itself is impossible. Your answer can make some assumptions as long as it sticks to the core question: how long would it take for something very large and very heavy and very hot to cool down?

Comment: for comparison: Earth's much smaller than the Sun, has no exothermic reaction going on in its core, and it's still hot enough to melt rock.

Comment: I'm guessing you are familiar with Newtons law of Cooling...https://m.carolina.com/teacher-resources/Interactive/newtons-law-of-cooling/tr36401.tr#:~:text=Newton's%20law%20of%20cooling%20states,than%20in%20a%20hot%20room.

Comment: It's hard to calculate this, but Barrow & Tippler (1986) estimate ~100,000 times the current age of the universe. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dwarf

Comment: @PM2Ring yes but is this not due to millions of years of ongoing fusion? My question pertains to an object that is hot but not actively producing heat, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @StudyStudy No I'm not but that sounds relevant! If the numbers can apply to a mind bogglingly large object then perhaps the answer is within reach?

Comment: If the Sun loses energy, it's interior temperature increases. So there is that to consider.

Comment: @Behacad A white dwarf is no longer actively producing heat via nuclear fusion.

Comment: You can also get heat from gravitational collapse, and from changes of state, eg a liquid freezing into a solid.

Comment: You can't answer a physics question by ignoring the physics of what would happen. A star-sized meatloaf is a star with an unusual composition and it will behave like a star. It will undergo nuclear fusion and then will end up as a cooling white dwarf, supported by electron degeneracy pressure.

Comment: @JohnDvorak - ongoing nuclear fission in the core does provide some heat

Comment: You could change your question to ask about something where the physics you are interested in would apply. i.e. Something a LOT smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume sphericity, assume zero internal heat generation, and ignore gravity, as you specify, we can apply the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) in [radial coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) as

$$\nabla^2 T(r,t)=\frac{1}{\alpha(T)}\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial t};$$
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha(T)}\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial t},$$

where $T$ is temperature, $r$ is the distance from the center, $\alpha(T)$ is the thermal diffusivity of the material (itself a function of temperature), and $t$ is time. The initial condition is the initial temperature profile $T(r)$ at time $t=0$, and the boundary condition is the sum of the various heat fluxes (e.g., convection, radiation) from the surface.

(Edit: Another answer in this thread makes the assumption of a [uniform internal temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model), suitable for a [Biot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot_number) much smaller than one. But the Biot number scales linearly with size, so large solid objects have large Biot numbers. Thus, I'd say that this assumption is out of the question when the context is specifically an enormous object.)

Additional simplifying assumptions are possible. If the material is only slightly hotter than room temperature, dry, and sits on an insulated surface, then the material properties doesn't vary much and convection dominates over other heat loss mechanisms, and the boundary condition can be simplified to

$$\left.-k\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=R}=h[T(R,t)-T_\infty],$$

for example, where $k$ is the thermal conductivity, $h$ is the convective coefficient, $R$ is the radius, and $T_\infty$ is the surrounding temperature.  (This equation simply equates the conductive heat flux just inside the surface with the convective heat flux just outside the surface.)

Alternatively, if we assumed predominantly radiative heat loss (from a very hot object), we'd have

$$\left.-k(T)\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=R}=\sigma\epsilon[T(R,t)^4-T_\infty^4],$$

where $\sigma$ is the Stefan–Boltzmann constant and $\epsilon$ is the surface emissivity.

Still, even these simplifications require a dive into solution strategies—analytical and numerical—for partial differential equations.

**As a simpler scaling approach**, we ignore the temperature dependence of material properties, replace our first (partial differential) equation with its finite-difference equivalent,

$$\frac{\Delta T}{R^2}\sim\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\Delta T}{t},$$

and obtain the well-known scaling relation for diffusion

$$t\sim\frac{R^2}{\alpha}.$$

where $t$ now represents a characteristic time constant. Within one or several time constants, the heat transfer process is mostly completed, and a fair fraction of any initial temperature difference has been eliminated—independent of how large that difference was.

The thermal diffusivity of beefsteak (and pretty much all continuous, moist foods) is just about that of water, or about $10^{-7}\,\mathrm{m^2\,s^{-1}}$. The radius of the Sun is about $10^9\,\mathrm{m}$, but we cannot ignore gravity in this case. Instead, let's consider a radius of 10 m. The corresponding characteristic time constant is $10^{9}\,\mathrm{s}$, or $100\,\mathrm{y}$. This strikingly shows how slowly diffusion acts over reasonably large distances.

Comment: Wow amazing. This is over my head for sure! Just so we're clear: An enormous sun-sized beefsteak that is the temperature of the sun would take 10,000,000,000,000,000 years to cool down on its own? I assumed it would be a long time, but that is probably a few zeroes more than I expected.

Comment: Diffusion is very slow for long distances.

Comment: As said by @Chemomechanics, the time constant for a combined system with internal heat conduction (not diffusion) + external heat convection scales as a ratio for $(V/A)^2$ (volume over area) divided by $\alpha = k/\rho \tilde{C}_p$. For the same material in a system with all else being equal, larger objects take correspondingly more time to cool down. Radiative heat loss will play a role to shorten the time presented in this answer, causing the initial cooling rate to be significantly higher.

Comment: @Behacad it’s worth noting that a photon generated at the center of the sun takes on the order of 100,000 years to diffuse out to the surface, and then a mere 8 minutes to reach the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question really depends on what you want to consider. I guess the first thing to do is look at the heat capacity of the meatloaf as well as if you want to include effects like heat transmission within the meatloaf or just assume that it is always homogeneously hot. If you want to include this it is likely to be a lot more involved. Secondly there are two main effects I can think of:

1. radiative cooling. This can probably be reasonably estimated by considering black body radiation of the meatloaf and it's radiated power as a function of temperature and surface. This is given by the Stefan-Boltzmann law

$P = AT^4\sigma\epsilon$

Here $T$ is the Temperature, $\sigma$ the Stefan-Boltzmann constant, $A$ the surface area of your meatloaf, and $\epsilon$ the emissivity, that you can estimate by looking at various known materials if you can't find a precise measurement for a meatloaf.

Now if you know the specific heat capacity and density of your meatloaf you can calculate $T(E)$ i.e. the temperature as a function of the thermal energy stored in your meatloaf.
This is given by

$ T = \frac{E}{c m}$ , where $c$ is the specific heat capacity and $m$ the mass given by density $\times$ volume.

Then you can relate the change in temperature as a function of time $dT/dt$ to $dT/dt = dT/dE * dE/dt = - dT/dE * P(T)$ by the chain rule and the definition of power. The minus sign is used as the energy is radiated away from your meatloaf. This gives you a differential equation that you can solve and using your initial condition that $T(0) = T_{\text{sun}}$ you can calculate $t^*$ s.t. $T(t*) = 20 °C$.

If I made no mistake here the differential equation is

$dT/dt = - A \sigma \epsilon T^4/mc$ which is separable and has solution

$ t= -1/3*(1/T_0^3 - 1/T^3) mc/A\sigma\epsilon $

where $T_0$ is the initial temperature and $t$ is the time.

After you plug in the various values you should get a result in seconds.

Note that we have not included cooling by convection here which is arguably the bigger effect depending on the surroundings of your meatloaf but that is nothing I am willing or able to calculate in somewhat reasonable time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For $T_0>T$, it seems you obtain a negative number for $t$.

Comment: That is very true I probably missed a minus sign somewhere along the way